# how to extract specific variable to to fill another cell value?

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset created for this example

```
/*sample data*/
data have;
input subj param value visit$ base;
cards;
        1   1   50      scr     .   
        1   1   55      rand    55
        1   1   .       1       55
        1   1   .       2       55
        1   2   120     scr     .
        1   2   125     rand    125
        1   2   .       1       125
        1   2   .       2       125 

;
run;
```

I want to make sure that the `base` value of `scr` is the same as 'base' when `visit`='rand' so that it looks like the following

```
/*sample data*/
data want;
set have;
input subj param value visit$ base;
cards;
        1   1   50      scr     55  
        1   1   55      rand    55
        1   1   .       1       55
        1   1   .       2       55
        1   2   120     scr     125
        1   2   125     rand    125
        1   2   .       1       125
        1   2   .       2       125 

;
run;
```

Comment: The question is clear, so I'm not sure who downvoted, but @Natha should include what s/he has tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double do-loop:

```
data want;
   do until(last.param);
      set have;
      by subj param notsorted;
      if visit='rand' then temp=base;
   end;
   do until(last.param);
      set have;
      by subj param notsorted;
      if visit='scr' then base=temp;
      output;
   end;
   drop temp;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this.  Assuming the data is not huge in size, use a hash table to update the values.

Get the `%create_hash()` macro from [here](https://github.com/FinancialRiskGroup/SASPerformanceAnalytics/blob/master/performance_analytics_library/macro/create_hash.sas)

```
data have;
input subj param value visit$ base;
cards;
        1   1   50      scr     .   
        1   1   55      rand    55
        1   1   .       1       55
        1   1   .       2       55
        1   2   120     scr     .
        1   2   125     rand    125
        1   2   .       1       125
        1   2   .       2       125 

;
run;

data want;
set have;
if _n_ =1 then do;
    %create_hash(lk,subj param,base,"have(where=(visit='rand'))");

/* The macro above generates the following code
declare hash lk(dataset:"have(where=(visit='rand'))");
rc = lk.definekey( "subj", "param" );
rc = lk.definedata("base");
rc = lk.definedone();
*/

end;

rc = lk.find();

drop rc;
run;
```

This reads the data set into memory and gives you a hash based look up into the values.  Use a subsetting `where` clause to only load the `rand` records into the hash.

Comment: is there a way to do this without using macro's ?

Comment: Yes, you can just expand the macro and write the code yourself.  try the code above with `options mprint;` to see the code that is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach, which uses SQL and joins the table with itself.

Not quite sure how to get back your original order, if that's important you may need to add a sort variable ahead of time.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select t1.subj, t1.param, t1.value, t1.visit, 
        case when visit='scr' then t2.base
        else t1.base 
        end as base
from have as t1
left join (select subj, param, base from have where visit = 'rand') as t2
on t1.subj=t2.subj
and t1.param=t2.param
order by 1, 2, 3, 4;
quit;
```